# ASP.NET Core MVC in Microsoft Store Commerce App

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC application and deployed it on a server. I am using Azure AD B2C in this application. The application is working fine.

I want to include this application in the Microsoft Store commerce app by using WebView. This is what I tried:

```
<x-ms-webview id="webview" src="<web app url>" style="width:100%; height:768px"></x-ms-webview>
```

The web application first shows a page which has a button to login and when clicking on that, it will redirect to the AD B2C login page. But in the store commerce app, it is showing the login button without its styles and when I click on that it is showing a white page only. What will be the reason?

The web application first shows a page which has a button to login and when clicking on that, it will redirect to the AD B2C login page. But in the store commerce app, it is showing the login button without its styles and when I click on that it is showing a white page only. What will be the reason?

Comment: After login have you tried accessing other pages? Did you see any error while checking the console logs?

Comment: The application flow is show a page which have login button. When click on that login button I am invoking asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn", this will load Azure AD B2C Sign in page. 
So it is showing first login button (but without it's applied style, just a text only). When click on it, showing just a white screen.